"mysql_config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable
Cuando intento instalar el modulo de Perl DBD:mysql en windows10 o windows 11 tengo el error:
tambien he intentado instalando el mysql y nada, todo igual
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7047 on perl 5.036003 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
Work directory is C:\Users\ADMINI~1/.cpanm/work/1721654559.2340
You have make C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gmake.exe
You have LWP 6.77
Falling back to Archive::Tar 3.02
Searching DBD::mysql () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-5.007.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DBD-mysql-5.007.tar.gz
Entering DBD-mysql-5.007
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Devel::CheckLib 1.09 ... Yes (1.16)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.70)
Checking if you have DBI 1.609 ... Yes (1.643)
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.184)
Configuring DBD-mysql-5.007
Running Makefile.PL
**"mysql_config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**


Que estas usando para instalar? Ya que es un ambiente de pruebas puedes hacerlo con XAMPP y cero lios

Bueno, uso XAMPP y cero lios, pero justo tengo una maquina que debe trabajar con una version de Perl 5.36 y el xamp funciona para la 5.32, en esta maquina tengo strawberry 5.36 y no deja instalar el DBD::mysql

Solo una duda, que tiene Perl 5.36 que no tenga el Perl 5.32??

Por alguna razon la gente de XAMPP facilitaron el trabajo del mysql y su XAMPP viene con Perl 5.32 si viniera con la 5.36 ya mi problema estarias solucionado.. Perl5.36 vino con algunas nuevas features que desconozco, pero lastimosamente no puedo trabajar con la 5.32 por politicas

La version de Strawberry Perl (5.36.3.1-64bit) Release Notes dice:
Known issues:
MSI package is not signed
TODO: libmysql needs updates before DBD::mysql can be built
Por lo cual opte por una que tiene las base de datos,  la version Strawberry Perl (5.32.1.1-64bit) :
Bundled database clients:
MySQL: DBD::mysql - works out of box
PostgreSQL: DBD::Pg - works out of box
Oracle: DBD::Oracle - install 64bit Oracle Instant Client 12.x and make sure you have OCI.DLL in your PATH
MS SQL: DBD::ODBC - install SQL Server ODBC client
